# How to change the date format of datepicker using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am using datepicker in jqgrid. Here, I want to get the date in the format of dd-mm-yy and i want to save the date on database in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. And whenever i retrieve date from database i will be in the format of dd-mm-yy.

How should we make it using jquery?

**Update**

```
<script>
            datePick=function(element)
                {
                    $(element).datepicker(
                        {
                            buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                            buttonImageOnly: true,
                            minDate: 0,
                            showButtonPanel: true ,
                            closeText: "Close",                                 
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true
                        }
                    ).attr('readonly','true');
                };
            function callme()
            {

                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy' );

            }

            function call()
            {

                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy' );
            }

            function fun()
            {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
            }
</script>
<body>
            <sjg:grid id="gridtable"
            ..............
            >
            .
            .
            .
            .
            .
                 <sjg:gridColumn
                name="custEstdDate"
                align="left"
                index="custEstdDate"
                title="Estd Date"
                sortable="false"
                editable="true"
                editoptions="{
                    size: 20,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    dataInit:datePick
                }"
               edittype="text"/>
               </sjg:grid>
```

These are my sample coding...

Comment: what language are you using server side to save to / load from database ?

Comment: are you using PHP for server side code ??

Comment: i am using struts2 and hibernate3.

Answer (score 2):

try [`dateformat()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) option of datecpicker

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
```

you can check the link for the avilable date format [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-parseDate)

or you can do that server-side ..change the format before inserting to the DB

**if using PHP**

```
 $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($posteddate));
```

**updated**

```
datePick=function(element)
            {
                $(element).datepicker(
                    {
                        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                        buttonImageOnly: true,
                        minDate: 0,
                        showButtonPanel: true ,
                        closeText: "Close",                                 
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" 
                    }
                ).attr('readonly','true');
               // $( element ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
            };
```

Comment: sorry. i couldn't get answer ..... I don't know why? Please see my coding and guide me. Thank you

Comment: are you getting any errors in your console.. i did update ny answer.. try it out.. though it does the same thing as previous update but you can try it out

Comment: i already tried this. It will work and it is always being the same format where ever i use it. but i want to change the date format before and after submitting. Please see my sample code.

Comment: then you don't you change date  format on serverside code... you can have one format to display and after submmiting change the format in server code

Comment: is there no way to change in client side?

Answer (score 1):

To change the date format in your datepicker, use

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'dd-mm-yy' );
```

The script you use on server side to insert to database should both convert to the desired database format, and reconvert when you want to display it.

Comment: It's also not working. can you guide me after see my sample coding. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
Suppose you have a div like:
 `<div id="datepicker"></div>`

Then you can do it like:

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
```

or

```
var dateTypeVar = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', dateTypeVar);
```